# Downloading in IntentService and Foreground services freezes the UI (Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, service, xamarin.android

I'm using an Intent Service to get streams of data from an API to write it inside a file on the user's device.

I can successfully stream the content and write it to a file inside the app. This works for small files, but for big files, it freezes the UI.
Taking this into consideration, I decided to put the download code inside a Foreground service. hopping everything will work well. but to my surprise, the UI still freezes.

I did the same thing inside an IntentService but it still freezes the UI.

```
[Service]
public class ProductFileDownloadService : Service
{
    ProductModel _product;
    Handler _handler;
    Action _runnable;
    private IProductFileService _productFileService;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        _handler = new Handler();
        _runnable = new Action(async () =>
        {
            try
            {

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async o =>
                {
                    DownloadCompleted downloadCompleted = OnDownloadCompleted;
                    DownloadProgress downloadProgress = OnDownloadProgress;
                    _productFileService.Register(_product.Id, downloadCompleted);
                    _productFileService.Register(_product.Id, downloadProgress);
                    await _productFileService.DownloadProductWithStreamAsync(_product);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        });
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals(AndroidConstants.StartNotificationReportService))
        {
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            byte[] prodByte = intent.GetByteArrayExtra(AndroidConstants.ProductExtra);
            byte[] prodDwnService = intent.GetByteArrayExtra(AndroidConstants.ProductDownloadServiceExtra);
            var jsonObject = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(prodByte);
            var prodDwnJObj = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(prodDwnService);
            _product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductModel>(jsonObject);
            //_productFileService = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductFileService>(prodDwnJObj);
            _productFileService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IProductFileService>();
            RegisterForegroundService();
            _handler.Post(_runnable);
        }

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private void OnDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        var notification = CreateNotification((float)(e.Percent * 100));

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(_product.Id, notification);
    }

    private void OnDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopForeground(true);
    }

    public override IBinder? OnBind(Intent? intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Notification CreateNotification(float percentage)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SingleProductView));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        int pendingIntentId = new Random().Next(100000);
        var notifId = _product.Id;
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot | PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NotificationsUtilities.DownloadNotificationChannelId)
            .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
            .SetContentText($"{Math.Round(percentage, 2)}% {_product.Title}")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notif)
            .SetContentIntent(pending)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();

        return notification;
    }

    void RegisterForegroundService()
    {
        var notification = CreateNotification(10);
        // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
        StartForeground(_product.Id, notification);
    }
}
```

I did the same thing inside an Intent Service, but the result was the same.
In the intent service, I just changed my Service's base type to "IntentService" and Carried the code contained in "_runnable" inside the "Handle" method of intent services.
But nothing works !!! I still get the same lag.

Please can someone help?
I have tried the "DownloadManager" but, the API from which I download requires clients to stream content bytes by bytes.

Comment: What is the version of your device? IntentService is subject to all the background execution limits imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26). Consider using WorkManager or JobIntentService, which uses jobs instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher. Please check the link below. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService